# stop fetching related entities in jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following data model:

- there are role groups and roles
- each role can belong to one or more role groups (many-many)
- there are privileges
- each privilege can belong to one or more role (many-many)

This is the entity definition:

role group:

```
public class RoleGroup {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_role_group")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_role_group", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "role_groups_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

role:

```
public class Role {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_role")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_role", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
  private List<AppUser> users;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "roles_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Privilege> privileges;
}
```

Now, I want to query all the role groups (id, name) with the corresponding roles (id, name), without any additional data like privileges.

For this, I created this dtos:

```
public class RoleGroupWithRolesDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<RoleDto> roles;
}

public class RoleDto {
    @NotNull(groups = {Existing.class})
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(groups = {New.class, Existing.class})
    private String name;

}
```

Then I have this query in the repository interface:

```
public interface RoleGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleGroup, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = {
            "roles" })
    List<RoleGroup> findAll();

}
```

With this I get the right data in the right structure according to the dtos, but the privileges are queried too (with extra queries). Of course, this is because of the fetched `roles` field, because all the other properties of a `role` will be fetched eagerly. But I don't need it. I need from the `role` entity only the `id` and `name` fields.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Tried `JPQL` or a specific `native query` ? Obvious since you mentioned yourself, as you have defined the mappings it will fetch the other fields too , either in Lazy or eager fashion

Comment: Yes, I tried both. But in the `RoleDto` I defined only `id` and `name` and no `privileges`. But despite of that I get the `privileges` too. I unterstand, this is because I fetch the `roles` too. I have to find an other solution.

Comment: But if you don't want it at the current stage, why don't you just remove it from Role class ? May be later you can fetch `priviledges` by a native query

Answer (score 0):

How do you verify that the collections of a `Role` are initialized? Through your debugger I guess? Note that the debugger will call the `toString` method of objects when presenting you the object contents, which will cause the initialization of lazy collections.

Maybe it's also the fault of your object mapper though, not sure how you do that. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(RoleGroup.class)
public interface RoleGroupWithRolesDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`RoleGroupWithRolesDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, RoleGroupWithRolesDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<RoleGroupWithRolesDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!